# jQuery sortable does not order properly in Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, zend-framework, sql-update

I'm trying to change order of images in my database width jQuery.
Before making any changes, MySQL DB looks like this:

```
image_id     image     belongs_to
1            1.png     356
2            2.png     356
3            3.png     356
4            11.png    600
5            22.png    600
6            33.png    600
7            44.png    600
8            111.png   121
9            222.png   121
10           333.png   121
11           1111.png  543
12           2222.png  543
13           3333.png  543
```

In the View part I'm listing this table:

```
<ul id="sortable">

   <?php

        for ($i=0; $i < count($this->images); $i++) { 
            echo "<li id='item_" .$this->images[$i]->image. "' style='background: url(" .$this->baseUrl. "/img/upload/" .$this->images[$i]->image. ") center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></li>";
        }

    ?>

</ul>
```

And sending data to controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#sortable").sortable({ 
                update : function () { 
                    var order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize'); 
                    $("#info").load("<?php echo $this->baseUrl; ?>/admin/sort?"+order); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
</script>
```

After updating DB with sort() method in Controller:

```
public function sortAction() {

        $images = new Application_Model_DbTable_Images();
        foreach ($_GET['item'] as $position => $item)
        {
            $test = array(
                'image' => $item,
                );
            $where = $images->getAdapter()->quoteInto('image_id = ?', $position);
            $images->update($test, $where);


        }
    }
```

I get strange results. My DB looks like:

```
 image_id     image     belongs_to
    1         1111.png     356
    2         3333.png     356
    3         2222.png     356
    4            11.png    600
    5            22.png    600
    6            33.png    600
    7            44.png    600
    8            111.png   121
    9            222.png   121
    10           333.png   121
    11           1111.png  543
    12           2222.png  543
    13           3333.png  543
```

The problem is that only first records change.
There should be only swap within the appropriate group.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: if the sort algorithm doesn't provide you with the expected result, you should make your own. This is perfectly sorted based on image name. What is the result you'd expect ?